# JS Appending string as function parameter is giving a weird output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that creates and "a" tag and appends it a div using Jquery's .innerHTML function.  Im trying to define the function onclick will call and pass a string as it's parameter. However, when running the code the string changes, white space is replaced with this ( =" "). Which is strange because the same string is used elsewhere in the tag and is printed correctly. Here's my code:

```
var companies = companyString.split(",");
var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropdown');

for (var item in companies){
    var str = "World Wrestling Entertainment";  //example

    dropDown.innerHTML = dropDown.innerHTML + "<a href='#' onclick='filterCompany('"+str+"')'>"+str+"</a>";
}
```

any ideas?

thanks

this  gets spit out in html as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="filterCompany(" world="" wrestling="" entertainment')'="">World Wrestling Entertainment</a>
```

Comment: Nothing weird about it, just the logical result of you messing up the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just muddled the quotation marks a bit. This should work:

```
var companies = companyString.split(",");
var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropdown');

for (var item in companies){
    var str = "World Wrestling Entertainment";  //example
    dropDown.innerHTML = dropDown.innerHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="'+'filterCompany('+"'"+str+"'"+')'+'">'+str+'</a>';
}
```

Comment: thanks I did it your way but quotes around the string were still missing so I added &quot; around the str and it works now ;)